# Route connections through VPN, then through Orbot

Tags: vpn, tor

Currently I'm using "OpenVPN for Android", OrWall and Orbot in order to route connections through VPN, then through Orbot. So it looks like this:

App -> VPN -> Orbot

This is great, but it's not an optimal way to do it, because OrWall is outdated and is not being developed any further. It has some security issues and I'm sure sooner or later (perhaps with Android Nougat) it will cease to work.

Is there any other way to route apps through Tor / Orbot, but have them go through a VPN first, so as not to connect to Tor directly from the ISP's IP?

Answer (score 0):

Not to familiar  with open vpn but if you have a integrated vpn then use tor that would work. http://www.howtogeek.com/135036/how-to-connect-to-a-vpn-on-android/

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).